# Flutter How to get information about battery usage by application

Tags: flutter, dart

to know % of battery used by application.

What I need is the information that's available on an Android device under "Settings -> Battery stats"

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way of doing this in Flutter, let alone Android. See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15518191/12806961) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35627166/12806961) for an explanation on why this is so difficult.

As mentioned in the other answer, you can use the [battery_info](https://pub.dev/packages/battery_info) package to get general info about the battery as a whole but it will not give you information specific to your app.

Keep an eye on this [unfinished Flutter documentation page](https://docs.flutter.dev/perf/power) for more info.

Comment: Canot we use package `device_info` or `BatteryInfo` just to show the battery percentage of an application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Android's Battery historian script](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/setup-battery-historian) (which I have no affiliation with).

It gives you stats of battery usage overall and for your apps for Android.